# LINQ to XML gets no data with schema set

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get some XML data with LINQ, but running into a problem.

I am using a schema, which is set in the attribute xmlns ...

```
<CarsForSale xmlns="http://schemas.sharplogic.net/CarSales.xsd">
  <CarForSale>
```

There are many CarForSale elements.

When the schema is set and I do this...

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/XML/CarsForSale.xml"));

var cars2 = from d in doc.Descendants("CarForSale")
            select d;
```

Then I get in the results i get Enumeration yielded no results

Strip the xmlns out of the XML file and the data comes back as expected??

Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to prepend the namespace:

```
var ns    = "http://schemas.sharplogic.net/CarSales.xsd";
var cars2 = from d in doc.Descendants(ns + "CarForSale")            
            select d;
```

otherwise search by local name:

```
var cars2 = from d in doc.Descendants()
            where d.Name.LocalName == "CarForSale"            
            select d;
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid hard coding the namespace you can use this:

```
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
```